# update trial version database without delete old one

Tags: android

I am implementing an android application and i can't figure out how to solve this problem

I'm trying to deploy an application with an existing SQLite database.

when user install application at the first time , Database will download but as trial version ,  with few records only , there are 10 feature extra than trial version when user select to buy one of them database should updated with new records from server , new records have the same schema of trial version database , so i want to insert purchased records to old database without delete old version and install new one with purchased feature

Comment: Why not just replace the whole thing?  What is the purpose of keeping the original?

Comment: because it is not logic , i say application have 10 feature , user can buy feature 1 and 2 another can buy 2 and 3 another can buy 1 and 2 and 3 there are Permutations and combinations of 10 . totally create databse of 10 Permutations and combinations unlogic

Comment: i want to explain database is sqlite

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the most direct method would be to have separate text files containing the SQL commands to insert the data for each different upgrade.

Then your app can download said file, read the text file and execute the SQL commands contained therein, adding the data necessary.

You could either have the raw SQL in the file and use the `rawQuery()` method (somewhat dangerous IMO) or you can create a data structure to be read in by your app that takes the data and drops it into a method that can be parameterized like `.insert()`.